# Mysql 3 tablas a consultar con condición

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Deseo hacer una consulta a 3 tablas que están en la misma base de datos.

- `wp_temperatura`
- `wp_pressure`
- `wp_altitude`

De la consulta quiero obtener 2 parámetros de cada una de ellas.

- De `wp_temperatura` parámetros: `temperatura` e `Insertado_temp`
- De `wp_pressure` parámetros: `presion` e `Insertado_press`
- De `wp_altitude` parámetros: `altitud` e `Insertado_alt`

adjunto foto de las tres tablas:
[image: foto3tablas]

El campo `"Insertado"` de cada una de ellas ya lo he cambiado a `Insertado_temp`, `Insertado_press` e `Insertado_alt` para diferenciar las fechas de registro de los tres parámetros.

Lo que tienen en común las 3 tablas es que alguno de estos registros pueden tener el mismo `IdObjeto`, aunque no necesariamente.

Los parámetros que quiero obtener de cada uno de las tres tablas deben tener el mismo `IdObjeto` y además este `idObjeto` debe ser:

> "C-136a660f-5af4-4d4d-820e-67af81c912ff"

El error que obtengo con el siguiente código que he probado en `MySql` es:

> ***#1054 - Unknown column 'wp_temperatura.idObejto' in 'where clause'***

Este es el código:

```
SELECT 
      wp_temperatura.temperatura, 
      wp_temperatura.Insertado_temp, 
      wp_pressure.presion, 
      wp_pressure.Insertado_press, 
      wp_altitude.altitud, 
      wp_altitude.Insertado_alt 
FROM
      wp_temperatura, wp_pressure, wp_altitude 
WHERE 
      wp_temperatura.idObejto = "C-136a660f-5af4-4d4d-820e-67af81c912ff"  
      AND wp_pressure.idObjeto = "C-136a660f-5af4-4d4d-820e-67af81c912ff" 
      AND wp_altitude.idObjeto = "C-136a660f-5af4-4d4d-820e-67af81c912ff";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el mensaje de error se ve que hay un simple error de escritura:

> wp_temperatura.idObejto

Debería ser

```
wp_temperatura.idObjeto
```

Comment: Gracias Shaz. Es correcta tu respuesta, pero Markos Aguilar respondió antes por tanto por orden debo marcar su respuesta como valida. Aun así muchas gracias.

Comment: Si re fijas bien yo respondi como 10 minutos antes que él.  El orden en el que aparecen las respuestas no es cronológico.

Comment: Hola. Shaz. No me había dado cuenta. Ya lo he cambiado. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El error dice que no encuentra la columna:

> wp_temperatura.idObejto

Cambialo por:

> wp_temperatura.idObjeto

Esto solucionará el problema porque es el nombre real del campo.

Comment: La verdad no veo que agrega tu respuesta de nuevo, comparada con la otra que ya estaba.